# Is "Tom Hammond" a reference to something?

Tags: reference, king-of-the-hill

In [The Accidental Terrorist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1195645/?ref_=ttmc_mc_tt), Hank finds out he's been getting scammed by his regular car salesman, Tom Hammond. In response, he prints out a large number of flyers that say "Tom Hammond's World of Lies", planning to spread them around Hammond's lot. While at the print shop, he has this exchange with Alex, a random young man:

> ALEX: *(looking at a flyer)* Ain't it the truth.
>
> HANK: Yes it is. And I'm telling you right now, that Tom Hammond has got to be stopped.
>
> ALEX: I know! I did a whole term paper on the damage people like Tom Hammond are doing to the world.
>
> HANK: Well, there is no way I'm letting Tom Hammond make this world a place that I don't want my son to live in.
>
> ALEX: *(nodding)* I wanna join your fight.

During the scene, there's a lot of emphasis on Tom Hammond's name. It's said three lines in a row, and in Hank's last line he draws it out.

Hankd and Alex meet the next morning at 5 AM at Hammond's dealership. Hank spreads flyers on his half of the lot, while unbeknownst to him, Alex is setting fire to the cars on the other half.

It seems unlikely that Alex wrote a term paper about a car salesman. The entire situation makes it feel like a joke around the name "Tom Hammond" leading to a case of mistaken identity. However, the only Tom Hammond I found was [a play-by-play basketball commentator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Hammond) at the time the episode was made, and doesn't appear to fit as the target of the joke in any way.

Is there any evidence (in-universe, interviews, whatever) that this episode is poking fun at something or someone? Or am I reading too much into this, and Alex is just a kid who wants to burn something down?